# Uploading a File from a Remote Server to an FTP Server with PHP

Tags: php, ftp

How can I upload a remote file from a link for example, `http://site.com/file.zip` to an FTP server using PHP? I want to upload 'Vanilla Forum Software' to the server and my mobile data carrier charges high prices, so if I could upload the file w/o having to upload it from my mobile I could save money and get the job done too.

Comment: Is the file that big to make `file_get_contents('http://site.com/file.zip')` useless? I think the wording in your question is kind of twisted. My guess is that you have access to your host, where you want to upload the remote file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Made you this function:

```
function downloadfile($file, $path) {
    if(isset($file) && isset($path)) {
            $fc = implode('', file($file));
            $fp = explode('/', $file);
            $fn = $fp[count($fp) - 1];

                if(file_exists($path . $fn)) { 
                    $Files = fopen($path . $fn, 'w');
                } else {
                    $Files = fopen($path . $fn, 'x+');
                }
                $Writes = fwrite($Files, $fc);
                if ($Writes != 0){
                    echo 'Saved at ' . $path . $fn . '.';
                    fclose($Files);
                }
                else{
                echo 'Error.';
                }

    }

}
```

You may use it like this:

```
downloadfile("http://www.webforless.dk/logo.png","folder/");
```

Hope it works well, remember to Chmod the destination folder 777.
((If you need it to upload to yet another FTP server, you could use one of the FTP scripts posted in the other comments))

Best regards. Jonas

Comment: sorry about my english and my late reply. What I meant is to get the file www.example.com/ file.zip to ftp.somesite.com directly without downloading ww.example.com/ file.zip to my storage space and then uploading it to ftp.somesite.com. Thanks for all your replies

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
$con=ftp_connect("ftp.yourdomain.com");
$login_result = ftp_login($con, "username", "password");
// check connection
if ($conn_id && $login_result) {
    // Upload
    $upload = ftp_put($con, 'public_html/'.$name, "LOCAL PATH", FTP_BINARY);
    if ($upload) {
         // UPLOAD SUCCESS
    }
}
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Answer (score 1):

A ) download the file via an url :

```
$destination = fopen("tmp/myfile.ext","w");
//Myfile.ext is an example you should probably define the filename with the url.
$source = fopen($url,"r");
while (!feof($source)) {
  fwrite($destination,fread($source, 8192));
}
fclose($source);
fclose($destination);
```

B) Upload the file on FTP :

```
$file = 'tmp/myfile.ext';
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "UPLOAD OK";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
fclose($fp);
```

This just a quick example , there is probably lot of improvement which can be done on this code , but the main idea is here.

Note : if you have a dedicated server it's probably faster and easier to download the file with a call to wget.

More info on FTP can be found [in the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/ref.ftp.php)

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
copy('ftp://user:pass@from.com/file.txt', 'ftp://user:pass@dest.com/file.txt');
```

The PHP server will consume bandwidth upload and download simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Create a php script in a web-accessible folder on your target server, change the values of $remotefile and $localfile, point your browser to the script url and the file will be pulled.

```
<?php
$remotefile="http://sourceserver.com/myarchive.zip";
$localfile="imported_archive.zip";
if(!copy($remotefile, $localfile))  {
    echo("Transfer Failed: $remotefile to $localfile");
}
?>
```